# SQL Injection vulnerablities in ASP script

Tags: sql, asp-classic, sql-injection

Right now I have a sample ASP script below:

```
    <%Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objConn.Open Application("WebUsersConnection")
    sSQL="SELECT * FROM Users where Username=? & Request("user") & _"?and Password=? & Request("pwd") & "?
    Set RS = objConn.Execute(sSQL)
    If RS.EOF then
       Response.Redirect("login.asp?msg=Invalid Login")
    Else
       Session.Authorized = True
    Set RS = nothing
    Set objConn = nothing Response.Redirect("mainpage.asp")
    End If%>
```

May I know what kind of SQL Injection will be caused by this script? What's the result of the execution, and any sample SQL that can inject into application with the above script? It's extracted from the paper. Thanks

Comment: I don't think it's correctly extracted, your quoting when setting sSQL looks a bit off.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, Can you please give me some hint on where's the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problem of directly writing user input into a SQL query:

```
sSQL="SELECT * FROM Users where Username='" & Request("user") & "' and Password='" & Request("pwd") & "'"
```

is that if user submitted

```
username' OR 1=1 --
```

which makes your query eventually looks like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Users where Username='username' OR 1=1 --' and Password=''
```

depending on your database driver, this may return at least one row, making your script think this is a valid user (or even an admin, if defaultly sort by id ascending).

You can use [`ADODB.Command`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object to prepare SQL query and bind value to placeholder.

Something like this:

```
sSQL="SELECT * FROM Users where Username=? and Password=?"
set objCommand=CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objCommand.Prepared = true
objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConn
objCommand.CommandText = sSQL
objCommand.Parameters.Append objCommand.CreateParameter("name",200,1,50,Request("user"))
objCommand.Parameters.Append objCommand.CreateParameter("password",200,1,64,Request("pwd"))
objCommand.Execute
```

MSDN doesn't seem to clear on whether `ADODB.Command` will actually treat query and value separately, but I guess for "modern" database driver, this is supported. If I remember correctly, this works on Oracle OLEDB database driver.

[MSDN on `ADODB.Command` properties and methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675022%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following two steps to protect against SQL injection with ASP for years on high traffic sites and never had an issue yet.

1. For each char datatype, make sure you replace any apostrophes with double apostrophes like this:

   ```
   sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE "
   sql = sql & "Username = '" & Replace(Request("user"), "'", "''") & "' "
   sql = sql & "AND Password = '" & Replace(Request("pwd"), "'", "''") & "'"
   ```
2. For any number (non char) fields, verify that the input isNumeric first, otherwise ignore it, or return an error.

Answer (score 0):

It is always good to use Regular Expressions to check for characters in the input (querystring / form variables / etc...) before you pass them onto your database for processing. The check should be done to see if all the characters in the input are within the allowed characters (whitelist check).

```
Function ReplaceRegEx(str, pattern)
set pw = new regexp
pw.global = true
pw.pattern = pattern
replaced = pw.replace(str, "") 'Find the pattern and store it in "replaced"
ReplaceRegEx = replace(str,replaced,"") 'Replace with blank.
End Function

'below is a sample. you can create others as needed
Function UserNameCheck(x)
UserNameCheck = ReplaceRegEx(x,"^[a-zA-Z_-]+$")
End Function
```

And this is how you call it in your ASP page:

```
fld_UserName=UserNameCheck(fld_UserName)
if fld_UserName="" then 
    'You can probably define the below steps as function and call it...
    response.write "One or more parameters contains invalid characters"
    response.write "processing stopped"
    response.end
end if
```